# Filtering with column of nullable integer type in pandas

Tags: pandas

What is the correct way to filter a column with a dtype of Int64Dtype?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1,2,None], 'B' : [3,4,np.nan]},dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
df
      A     B
0     1     3
1     2     4
2  <NA>  <NA>

df[df['A'] == 1]

ValueError: cannot mask with array containing NA / NaN values
```

Comment: Upgrade your pandas version.

Comment: Is this R or pandas ?  <NA> look like R

Comment: Hey, It is working fine, please upgrade your Pandas as @ScottBoston already said.

Comment: Upgrading did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions to update pandas did the trick. Thanks.

In anaconda,

```
conda update --all
pd.__version__
'1.0.5'
```